# When you're ask culture, how can you tell the difference between polite guess culture comments and malicious backhanded comments?

Tags: ask-or-guess

I'm ask-culture, and I suspect (though I'm not 100% sure) a colleague is guess-culture.  I, probably like everyone, have various insecurities about my job skills.  There are things I feel I'm very good at, and there are areas where I feel deficient.  I'm admittedly sensitive about areas where I feel I don't perform as well as my peers.  And this one colleague constantly makes what I immediately interpret as backhanded/underhanded comments.  I feel like they are sly digs/insults aimed at these deficiencies I feel I have.

I feel I go to great lengths to calm myself and not react defensively at these interpreted sleights.  There was a comment recently that really evoked my defensive reflex and I haven't responded at all for fear that I wouldn't be able to give a measured response, but I've been obsessing over the comment because it really bothers me.  So I've been analyzing it...

I'd like to keep this anonymous, so I'm not going to quote the comment or name the person, but at the same time, I'd like generally to understand guess culture enough to be able to tell whether a comment like theirs is a polite guess-culture suggestion that I work on improving my deficiencies or whether they're just being malicious.  So let me describe the comment without details to see if answers I receive can help me learn how to distinguish polite indirect guess culture suggestions versus malicious criticisms...

The comment is well couched in compliments.  To someone else, without context, it may seem very diplomatic.  It makes a seemingly benign direct suggestion of something I could have done differently.  However, it indirectly and subtly alludes to my deficient skills.  The commenter never suggests directly that I improve those skills, but repeatedly makes comments about mistakes I make, suggesting simple solutions - but they are solutions (to X) that I wouldn't possibly think about given deficiency Y.  X and Y involve completely unrelated skills.  I can do X.  X is no problem.  My solution to X was correct and acknowledged (in the compliments).  They're suggesting something that is obvious to anyone, so I always feel like this is a criticism of my deficient skills surrounding skill/competency Y.

As an ask-culture person, I would feel imminently better if they just suggested I work on skill Y.  I know they *know* I'm very good at X, so to me, suggesting a better solution to X *has* to mean something else.  And for them to not directly make a statement about Y feels really offensive to me.  And to be honest, I'm not sure how to describe *why* it offends me.  Sure, I'm sensitive about my deficient skills.  But why is it I feel I would be more comfortable with a direct comment about improving skill Y than an indirect "suggestion" about improving skill Y?

My wife is guess-culture and her interpretation of the comment (even knowing the subtle context) was that it was a great example of a polite guess-culture suggestion that I work on skill Y.  She explained that a guess-culture person would be embarrassed and offended had it been a direct suggestion to work on Y.  She felt there was no diplomatic way to say it and I immediately gave an example of a way to suggest I work on my Y skills that would feel supportive to me, but she insisted it would come across to her as embarrassing and offensive - i.e. she would react in the same way I react to the guess-culture way of suggesting I work on skill Y.

However, this person makes these comments *all the time*.  So it feels to me like harping and constant insults.

And here's the thing... In both cases, the end result is the same.  My solution to X was correct.  They were suggesting an alternate way to get to my solution X that has these intangible benefits.  So in a way, it feels to me like improving skillset Y is a waste of time.  In fact, I feel pretty strongly about alternative things we should be doing that eliminate Y entirely from the equation.  Sure, I would like to be better at Y, and I will work on it.  I would just like to not feel insulted all the time.

So how do I know if the indirect skill Y comment is a dig or a polite guess-culture suggestion to work on Y?

Comment: You cannot know. Even the "fact" that they are guess-culture is just... a guess. Not a direct answer to your question, but: does it matter? You can work on your insecurities, or you can work on Y. Both might be a step closer to not having the problem you describe. But piling guess upon guess what someone maybe could have thought when they adressed you is not really a constructive way forward. Your problem will still persist, even if you guess correctly.

Comment: @nvoigt - that rings true. Maybe it's best to assume they think it's a polite way to suggest I work on Y. Just not sure how to get into that head space - or how to make that be my default interpretation.  That's a different question though.  Thanks for your comment.

Comment: I'd like to answer this, really, but I keep running into this contradiction. You say the solutions are things "that I wouldn't possibly think about" given your skill deficiency, but then also characterize them as "obvious to anyone." That just doesn't parse for me. Do you mean obvious to *everyone but you?* If so, isn't this person helping you with a personal blindspot?

Comment: To clarify, "obvious to anyone" who doesn't have deficiency Y, so in essence, yes. Though the solution to X is obvious to me once a Y error is called attention to, which is what I meant. There are formalized solutions to Y-related-issues that I have pushed for because I know that I'm not good at it, but my lobbying has met significant resistance (prob bec. they're all good at Y). That's a separate issue though. The issue is that these indirect comments are embarrassing and being ask-culture, I would feel better if he just directly talked to me about skill Y, bec I feel helpless to improve on Y

Comment: But he doesn't call attention to a Y error on my part. He points out the obvious X error. If he did point out the Y error, I could be like "Whoops, my bad. Sorry, no problem. I'll fix it." I think maybe he thinks my deficiency in Y is due to something easily remedied by simply doing Z, but rather my deficiency in Y is due to something else (W), which is out of my control. But we don't have that discussion, because to me, it's something I'm sensitive about. I try to do things to mitigate it, as I have successfully done in past jobs, which is related to the formalized Y solution I've pushed for.

Comment: And his elaborate X error explanations are completely unnecessary. The only purpose they serve is to emphasize the *implied* Y error on my part. And he does this publicly. It's excruciating and embarrassing and constant.

Comment: Even when I do Z, there are multiple issues stemming from Y errors. We worked on one X-issue recently where I stepped up my Z game, and even with that, there were multiple Y issues. And he tried to do the same thing - embarrass me about Y, but I thoroughly demonstrated my Z efforts and showed that we still have the Y problem. I.e. I did the thing he was subtly implying I should do to solve Y, but I demonstrated that didn't fix it. In fact, I think he let up on his harping on Y for awhile after that - and he actually took a few steps toward my formalized solution to Y.

Comment: I am having trouble understanding the example you are giving. I think that you are probably going to have to be more specific if you want a good answer, because its kinda shooting in the dark with your question as is. I understand not wanting to reveal your identity though, so your best bet might just be asking someone in real life who is adept socially such as a acheived member of toastmaster/ other social club.

Comment: Is this a workplace issue? Is this person your boss/superior or a colleague? Maybe asking or looking on workplace.stackexchange.com will give you ideas in that case.